# How to pass @HiddenFor value on post method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, hidden-field

This is my **ViewModel:**

```
public class TestViewModel
{
    public Object p1{ get; set; }
    public Type p2{ get; set; }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public testViewModel test1;
}
```

This is my **View:**

```
@model mainViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("updateAction", "controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    <fieldset>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.test1, "editorView")
    </fieldset>
}
```

**EditorView.cshtml**

```
@model testViewModel

 //<input type="hidden" value="@Html.AttributeEncode(Model.p2)" id="p2" name="p2" />  
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.p2)
```

**Controller method**

```
[HTTPPost]
public ActionResult updateAction(mainViewModel md)
{

    //ModelState.Clear();

    return View("Index");
}
```

Now on post method I couldn't get the value of P2 variable. I tried most possible ways to get hidden value on post method but none of them work. I think something with Type property which I was not able to populate.

Please suggest me the way to get the hidden value on controller post method.

Comment: I don't believe `Type` is serializable. You could look at the rendered HTML source and see what's in the hidden field.

Comment: I checked the HTML source code and it's returning a value based on the system type. If it's string then it's returning "System.String" value but somehow its not passing on controller post method.

Comment: Well, the ModelViewBinder is trying to convert the string to a Type, which I don't believe can be done natively. If you must have the Type, I think you'll need a custom ModelViewBinder. But it's been a few years, so you might want to wait for other answers :).

Comment: You cannot use `HiddenFor()` (or any other form control) to bind to a complex object (look at the html your generating - it will have `name="yourAssembly.Type"`.